# How can I check my authentication status using ADC with Google Cloud?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, bucket

im using Google Cloud Platform in order to use Bucket as my principal storage in my applicaction, i would like to check my authentication status and if its wrong or something throw an error and stop running my server.

I authenticate in google cloud with  Application Default Credentials (ADC).

I would like to get an answer how to check my authentication status using NodeJS

Comment: To what do you refer as `authentication status`?

Comment: When you use ADC you dont know if your credentials are ok until you make a petition, i want check this json first and if my credentials are not ok, stop my server.

Comment: Then my question is, do you want to check the JSON, if you can create tokens or if you can make calls to the service? In any case you need to make a request. Checking the JSON is meaningless since you only will know if it is well-formed or not but in practice it will not say more.

Comment: Then a request to obtain a token (I think since I'm not sure) will tell you if the SA exists in the project or not. If you get a token the SA exists. Then you may need to call the service with that token and if you get 403 the SA does not have permissions.

Comment: These steps are done by default using the GCP libs so you can use that and if you get an error when making an operation, simply terminate the app. Since you're not showing any code it's hard to give better suggestions